# Access Denied on SC Start Service

Tags: service, remote

I'm attempting to grant a AD Group the ability to stop/start a service without having to be a local administrator of or having RDP access to the Win Server 2008 machine. The permissions are being set through GPO and have been applied as you will notice in the screenshot. I'm able stop the service remotely without being an admin but get access denied when attempting to start the service.

Even though we don't want the group to have RDP access, I am able to stop/start the service when using RDC without admin access.

[CMD Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxa8l.png)

Does anyone know where I could go from here?

Answer (score 0):

We gave Full Control to the group and they were then able to start the service.